# XamlReader Dynamic Event using User-defined Code

Tags: xaml, events, dynamic, uwp

We are making use of XamlReader to allow users to dynamically define UI in our App.

For example, if they want to define Grid with multiple buttons, it can be done by defining xaml string.

```
var xaml = `
 <Grid  xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' Height='600' Background='Gray'>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width='2*' />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width='1*' />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width='1*' />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height='2*' />
                        <RowDefinition Height='1*' />
                        <RowDefinition Height='1*' />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Name='FirstName' xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' Text='TESTING' Grid.Row='0' Grid.Column='0' Height='20' />
                 <TextBox Name='LastName' xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation' Text='TESTING' Grid.Row='1' Grid.Column='0' Height='20'  />                
         <Button Grid.Column='1'>Button 2</Button>
                <Button Grid.Column='2'>Button 3</Button>
                <Button Grid.Column='1' Grid.Row='1'>Button 5</Button>
                <Button Grid.Column='2' Grid.Row='1'>Button 6</Button>
                <Button Grid.Row='2'>Button 7</Button>
                <Button Grid.Column='1' Grid.Row='2'>Button 8</Button>
                <Button Grid.Column='2' Grid.Row='2'>Button 9</Button>
</Grid>
`;

var control = Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlReader.Load(xaml) as UIElement;
```

However, we also want **users** to be able to define **events**. For example, clicking Button 1 will show a message box. Clicking Button 2 will do something else.

We want them to be able to specify the code themselves, similar to the XamlReader.Load.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. UWP does not allow you to generate or compile C# code at runtime. You could only create simple `Expression` trees, but that is not really useful in your case.

Also if you check the [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader), it says

> The XAML should not attempt to specify x:Class attribute, or include any XAML-defined attributes for event handlers

From this it is quite clear that it is not designed for this purpose.